# confused with autofs example

Tags: mount, nfs, autofs

I am exploring the autofs with ubuntu, and I got it working, but something doesn't quite make sense to me.

this is what I got:

```
$ pwd
/nfs/nfs/mnt/nfs_export
$ ls
kvm_the_1st.img  lost+found  success
```

as you can see it mounts successfully. My problem is the number of folders that exists as the path to get to my stuff.

My auto.master:

```
/nfs    /etc/auto.nfs
```

My auto.nfs:

```
nfs            -fstype=nfs4            nfs:/
```

on the NFS server I have the following for export:

```
/mnt/nfs_export *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I am guessing it is because my auto.master specifies /nfs, then my auto.nfs has another nfs, then the root directory that gets exported from the NFS right? But shouldn't it only export the nfs_export?

I had wanted to set it up so the /nfs would go directly to the export_nfs folder on the nfs server. Meaning if I cd into /nfs I should see files such as "success".

and a follow up question: I know via manual nfs via /etc/fstab I can change things such as rsize and wsize, but with autofs where/how would I make that change?